# need dell laptop 8200 wifi drivers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

i bought a dell inspiron 8200 on ebay,, it has no service tag on the bottom, when i installed my windows xp pro lost all drivers. in need to get the driver so i can run wifi on my laptop, were can i find this driver, have been looking al over free driver downloads

Answer (score 1):

[Dell's Drivers & Downloads](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&ServiceTag=&SystemID=INS_PNT_P4_8200&os=WW1&osl=en&catid=&impid=) have it available. You probably have the [True Mobile 1180 Internal 802.11b Mini-PCI Card](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R46482&SystemID=INS_PNT_P4_8200&servicetag=&os=WW1&osl=en&deviceid=2999&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=1&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=1&libid=5&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=54776).

Answer (score 0):

http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&os=WW1&osl=en&catid=&impid=&SystemID=INS_PNT_P4_8200 It should be under "network"